# Compile to linux executable with packed JRE

Tags: java, linux, executable

OK, so I want to essentially make a java app im working on completely standalone in a sense that to run it, you just slap it on a server and execute it.

Now, in order to do this, I'd need to pack the JRE into the executable, and actually create an executable.

So my question is: how do I turn my java project and or jar into a linux executable with JRE packed into it?

Comment: If you're using Java 14+ then check out [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) (preview feature Java 14-15, standardized Java 16).

Comment: Aside: As someone in a position to care about security for an enterprise software product, I would be extremely unhappy if one of my suppliers distributed their software this way (unless it were also available unbundled) and thus prevented me from installing security updates &c for the JVM.

Comment: Here's an example for [WIndows](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9) but you can ignore the obvious Windows-specific bits

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Didn't think about that. Though I believe `jpackage` is meant more for deploying to desktops of "average" users who want an application that "just works".

Comment: @Tran, ...that said, in the Linux world there's no expectation on the part of your users to have an application be a single executable. The expectation is that you'll distribute a distro-specific package that _has been tested for their distro_, and lists dependencies (JRE included), so the JRE they already have installed can be reused to run your program, and if the package manager downloads a JRE when they're telling it to install your program, then that same JRE will be used to also run the next Java program they install (reducing the total amount of space used).

Comment: Even programs that _do_ distribute all their dependencies take a subset of the filesystem tree for the purpose -- you get something like `/opt/oracle` when you install the Oracle database, and everything it needs -- _including_ the JRE -- goes somewhere under the tree. (To be clear, as a system administrator, I hate this, and I hated it even more when I automated Oracle installation and RAC configuration professionally back in the mid-2000s; one loses security properties FHS-compliant packaging provides).

Comment: ...part of the point of distro packages is to deploy software in such a way as to play nice for the distribution at hand -- f/e, if you know if you're targeting systemd, or upstart, or SysV init, you can provide service definitions appropriate to the OS at hand.